# Start iterating dataframe from a specific row

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame:

```
                  dt_object     price
0       1990-01-01 00:00:00  1.050067
1       1990-01-01 00:05:00  1.049700
2       1990-01-01 00:10:00  1.049933
3       1990-01-01 00:15:00  1.049733
4       1990-01-01 00:20:00  1.050033
```

I iterate it using

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index >= 9000000:
       #do_the_job
```

The data file is very large. I need to iterate over from index 9000000. Can I start iterating over once from this index? It takes a long time before the check from 0 to 9000000 passes.
I cannot truncate data from 0 to 9000000 because I am doing the calculation using past data. For the current row the result is calculated based on past values.

Comment: what about `df.iloc[start_index:].iterrows()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "pre-index" in the for loop:

Instead calling `df`, you could just call `df[idx_start:]`

```
for index, row in df[idx_start:].iterrows():
    #do_the_job
```

**Note**
Slicing in pandas take the columns, then instead `df[idx_start:]` it should be `df.loc[key_start:,:]` (with key map, it could be different from numbers) or `df.loc[idx_start:,:]` (with indexing from zero)

Answer (score 2):

You can slice the DataFrame:

```
for index, row in df.iloc[9000000:].iterrows():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pandas.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl', usecols=[col])
for i, row in df[239:].iterrows():
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
```